# Help with Formula Text Field

Tags: lightning-experience, formula-field

I am trying to create a formula returning one value based on certain parameters or a different value with other credentials. Right now, the only returned value is "AM Tenured."

```
IF(
    AND(
        Amount  <=  150000,
        CONTAINS (PartnerID_Slug__c , "smartbiz"),
        OR(
            CONTAINS(Lender__r.Name , "Cadence"),
            CONTAINS(Lender__r.Name , "Star")
        ),
        OR(
            Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 3,
            Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 4,
            AND(
                Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 2,
                Average_Credit_Score__c >= 675
            )
        )
    ),
    "AM Trainee",
    "AM Tenured"
)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide an example of the field values when your formula returns the wrong result?

Comment: Sure, I want this first part to return "AM Trainee":
AND(
        Amount  <=  150000,
        CONTAINS (PartnerID_Slug__c , "smartbiz"),
        OR(
            CONTAINS(Lender__r.Name , "Cadence"),
            CONTAINS(Lender__r.Name , "Star")

And I want this second part to return "AM Tenured"
 OR(
            Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 3,
            Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 4,
            AND(
                Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 2,
                Average_Credit_Score__c >= 675

Right now, all its returning is "AM Tenured"

Comment: It sounds like you need two "if" statements, then?

Comment: I think @DerekF is asking for sample data of the field values where you think it should return "AM Trainee", but instead it unexpectedly returns "AM Tenured".

Comment: I have an opp where the amount is $50,000, the slug is smartbiz and the lender is cadence, but it still returns "AM Tenured"

Comment: Comments are designed for users to *seek* clarification, not provide it. Please **[edit]** your post if you have anything to add to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're looking for two IF statements:

```
IF(
    AND(
        Amount  <=  150000,
        CONTAINS (PartnerID_Slug__c , "smartbiz"),
        OR(
            CONTAINS(Lender__r.Name , "Cadence"),
            CONTAINS(Lender__r.Name , "Star")
        )
    ),
    "AM Trainee",
    IF(
        OR(
            Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 3,
            Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 4,
            AND(
                Smart_Rate_NEW__c = 2,
                Average_Credit_Score__c >= 675
            )
        ),
        "AM Tenured",
        null
    )
)
```

Where we have `IF(Condition1, "AM Trainee", IF(Condition2, "AM Tenured", null))`; this allows you to have the various conditions be met. Note that I left a null in the final position; you'll want to put whatever you want here if none of the conditions are met.

Comment: @Moonpie Haha, thanks. It was mostly a copy-paste job, so something was bound to go wrong. 

Comment: Sorry - I deleted my comment after you edited. I wasn't expecting a reply.  My edits have to be >=6 characters, so I couldn't (easily) edit it myself. *[For context, my original comment was to (try to) subtly indicate a missing comma.]*

Comment: @Moonpie No worries, comments are meant for "permanent" conversations anyways. And, as you might imagine, this isn't the first time it's happened to me. Also, had you not commented, it wouldn't have been fixed until someone did, most likely.